# Unable to receive messages on ROS network

Tags: ros, network-setup, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently running a master node on my Jetson TK1(IP - 10.42.0.15) and a remote PC running ubuntu(IP - 10.42.0.1).
I have gone through all the setup shown in the [setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and [multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines). Also, I am able to ping into both of them and netcat results are perfect too.
I have also gone through ROS answers on setting up the /etc/hosts file. But, when I try to do the `rostopic list` after a `roscore` on tegra ,I just dont see anything.

my setup on tegra is:

```
export ROS_IP=10.42.0.15
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.42.0.15
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.15:11311/
```

Variables setup on PC are:

```
export ROS_IP=10.42.0.1
export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.42.0.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.15:11311/
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254407/unable-to-receive-messages-on-ros-network/) by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2017-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [epsilonjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25376/epsilonjon/) on 2017-02-11**:
When you run roscore on the master, what is printed to the command line?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-11**:
This could be `roscore` binding its socket to the wrong IP, good question @epsilonjon.

Also: @kartikmadhira1: using `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` at the same time is not recommended / necessary. I'd stick to `ROS_IP` if you are in fact not resolving hostnames.

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2017-02-11**:
@epsilonjon , The ros master is started with the given IP name and I'm able to run rplidar node too.

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2017-02-11**:
@gvdhoorn tried with only ROS_IP, but without any help. messages aren't coming.

**Comment by [epsilonjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25376/epsilonjon/) on 2017-02-11**:
@kartikmadhira1 Are you running `rplidar` and `rostopic list` on the master or on the other machine?

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2017-02-11**:
@epsilonjon `rplidar` on the master and `rostopic list` on PC.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:\

> @gvdhoorn tried with only ROS_IP, but without any help. messages aren't coming.

my comment wasn't meant as a "this will solve your problem" kind of comment, but more as a general remark. The semantics of the two variables are different. They shouldn't be used at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally figured it, firewall was at place in the master so did `sudo ufw disable` to allow port connections and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) with karma: 121 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2